# Restart n number of pods in K8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am working on an application which is running on the Kubernetes cluster. I want to restart the n number of pods manually in a sequence. Can we do that? Would `kubectl scale <options>` work here?

Comment: [`kubectl rollout restart`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-restart-em-) will restart every pod managed by a Deployment, which is often what I want for this case.  If it's one specific pod, `kubectl delete pod` that one pod.  And of course updating a deployment with a new `image:` will recreate all of its pods with newer code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on `restart n pods manually`? Do you want to restart only 5 out of 10 from your deployment or what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor problem not solved

Comment: @moonkotte yes i want to restart 5 out of 10 pods of a particular deployment

Comment: @ShubhamGupta Then yes, you're right, `kubectl scale deployment deploy-name --replicas=5` and then `kubectl scale deployment deploy-name --replicas=10` will restart exactly 5 pods (well, first command will terminate 5 pods and second will force controller manager to spin up 5 new pods). Or delete specific pods manually, kubernetes controller manager will take care of rescheduling enough `running and ready` pods within the deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **yes**, you can restart 5 out of 10 pods of a particular deployment. Though it won't be a single command for this.

As you correctly assumed `kubectl scale` will help you here.

Restart of 5 pods out of 10 contains 2 operations:

1. Scaling down the deployment from 10 to 5 pods

   ```
   kubectl scale deployment deployment-name --replicas=5
   ```
2. Scaling up the deployment from 5 to 10 pods back:

   ```
   kubectl scale deployment deployment-name --replicas=10
   ```

Also you can delete exact pods, `kube-controller-manager` with `deployment/replicaset` controllers within will make sure that `desired` state will match the exact state and therefore missing pods will be automatically rescheduled.

---

However following best practice (thanks to @DavidMaze), ideal scenario is restart the whole deployment. This can be done with following command:

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment deployment-name
```

This is safer option and it allows to roll back easily in case of any mistakes/errors.

Also it's possible to restart pods 1 by 1 within the deployment when `rollout restart` is requested.

`.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable` should be set to `1` which means only 1 pods at most will be unavailable during the restart - [reference to max unavailable](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable).

[Kubernetes Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)

Comment: this will be rolling restart and I want to restart the pods in sequence i.e one pod at a time will restart. If I go for scaling `kubectl scale` then it will restart all the remaining pods at once.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta You didn't mention anywhere about importance of sequence. Please update your question with all conditions and requirements. **To the topic**. The closest you can get is to set `.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable` to 1 which means when `rollout restart` is executed, all pods will be restarted 1 by 1. [See here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable). Unfortunately it's not possible to restart sequentially exact number of random pods within the same deployment using native kubernetes tools, only deleting selected pods.

Answer (score 1):

With replicaSet in place you can always scale up/down 'N' number of pods which will restart them and if you need to restart specific one simply delete them and RS will spin up a new one for you.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the bash script for this case. This shell script asks you for the replica_set-id, No of pods to be restarted and this script will delete/restart the pods in sequence.

```
#! /bin/bash
read -p "Replicaset-id: " p
pods=$(kubectl get pods | grep "$p" | awk '{print $1}')
read -p "No of pods to be restarted: " n
m=0
for pod in $pods
    do 
        ((m++))
        echo "$m"
        kubectl delete pod "$pod"
        if [[ "$m" -eq "$n" ]]; then
            break
        fi
    done
```

Comment: Yes, it will work. Approach you used is "delete pod manually and rely on replication controller to match a number of running pods in replicaset", but in automated version. What are you trying to achieve by doing it? Why do you need to restart several pods in a deployment? Why `rollout restart` doesn't work for you?